# perimeter finding on triangle LMO

Tags: geometry

Triangle LMO has vertices with the following coordinate points: 
L (4, 4)
M (0, 0)
O (4, 0)

how can I find its perimeter? I don't know how to find the hypotenuse
please help

Comment: Do you know two of the sides? Is it a right angled triangle?

Comment: Do you know Pythagoras' theorem: $a^2=b^2+c^2$?

Comment: Do you know distance formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: first find the perimeter of the square, LMAO

where A = (0,4)